# Rasterize rotated shapefile

Tags: qgis, gdal, rasterization

I want to rasterize a shapefile (I don't mind whether to use QGIS or python) but I want to rotate my shapefile first and than have my raster aligned to this rotation.

So lets say I rotate my shapefile by 30° (I can do this easily with QGIS), I then want to rasterize that projection of the data into a rectangular grid. Is that possible? I tried a quick search on the internet but I always find it hard to google gdal/qgis functions.

Comment: So, you want rotated pixels?

Comment: Yes, thats ultimately what i want.